# move_uploaded_file permission denied on 777 folder

Tags: php, laravel, upload

Here is the error I'm receiving when it tried to upload via ajax:

```
move_uploaded_file(/public/assets/uploads/photodune-5351272-asian-traditional-bell-l.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

My uploads folder is already set to 777 using chmod. This is the status of my folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jun 20 10:46 uploads
```

Here is the code I'm using on the PHP side:

```
if (Input::hasFile('file')) {

    $storeFolder = '/assets/uploads/';

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = public_path() . $storeFolder;
        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

        echo $targetPath . " / " . $targetFile;
    }

} else {
    echo "There has been an error in creating the file";
}
```

Why would I be still getting a permission denied when trying to use move_uploaded_file?

For the sake of testing, you can see the fileupload and the errors from here: http://www.relatient.net/relatientv2/public/portal/upload

Comment: `move_uploaded_folder`? what do you mean by that? `move_uploaded_folder` is not a function, or is it a Laravel-based function?

Comment: don't use this code. you're directly using `['name']`, which a malicious user can exploit to scribble their file ANYWHERE on your server. And you don't seem to be validating the upload at all, and simply assuming it succeeded, or that an upload was performed in the first place.

Comment: I'm using this statement to check if the file was uploaded: if (Input::hasFile('file')). I'll add validation and clean code when I get get the file to actually upload. And move_uploaded_folder was supposed to be move_uploaded_file. Brains kinda everywhere atm.

Comment: I remember seeing a similar question yesterday where using `public_path()` was the problem and the person who gave an answer suggested `asset` etc. just can't remember all the details.

Comment: Fred, it's not the issue, I've actually gave it the full path without using any function and it still gave me the same response as I'm getting with the public_path(). asset, it give u a html URL and not the local path on the server.

Comment: Have you tried setting your folder to `755` instead of `777`? That has worked for some in the past.

Comment: Just tried and it's giving me the same issue. So currently my folder is at 775: drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jun 20 11:44 uploads

Comment: is selinux active on the server?

Comment: I don't think selinux is even on the aws server were using.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the assets folder needed to be also set to 775 and laravel itself had to do this: ./composer.phar dumpautoload.

After doing this, everything is uploading ok.